# knit with `pdflatex --shell-escape myfile.tex`?

Tags: knitr, pdftex

I want to insert a word count into my .Rnw file.

To do this, I have the following line in `myfile.Rnw`:

```
\makeatletter\@@input|"echo `texcount -1 myfile.tex`| cut -c1-4"\makeatother
```

But this requires me to run `pdflatex` with the `--shell-escape` flag. With Sweave, I have a makefile that includes the line:

```
...
R CMD Sweave myfile.Rnw
pdflatex --shell-escape myfile.tex 
...
...
```

Is there a way to add the `--shell-escape` to pdflatex when I use knit instead of the makefile to compile the document?

---

#### Reproducible example:

contents of myfile.Rnw:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

Words: \makeatletter\@@input|"echo `texcount -1 myfile.tex`| cut -c1-4"\makeatother
Lorem ipsum dolor
\end{document}
```

what works:

```
R CMD Sweave myfile.Rnw
pdflatex --shell-escape myfile.tex
```

what doesn't work:

```
knit("myfile.Rnw")
"myfile.pdf" %in% dir() ## False
```

Answer (score 5):

After grepping for `pdflatex` in the knitr source code, I found the function `knit2pdf` with the argument `compiler`. This seems to work:

```
knit2pdf("myfile.Rnw", compiler = "pdflatex --shell-escape")
"myfile.pdf" %in% dir() ## TRUE
```

And to do this in Rstudio:

Tools -> options -> Sweave -> enable shell escape commands

Comment: `knit2pdf()` is only a convenience function, and I do not quite expect users to set `compiler` (it is kind of hack); I recommend the RStudio approach you mentioned, and what happens there is basically: `knit('myfile.Rnw'); pdflatex --shell-escape myfile.tex` (the second step is missing in your original post, and that is why `myfile.pdf` does not exist -- `knit()` alone does not compile tex)